# Syntax error: 'await' outside async function, but it works as a global variable?

Tags: python, async-await

I am pulling data using the `Binance API`, and want to store it (bitcoin price and time) in `two separate arrays`, then plot the data onto Matplotlib.

I have the following code:

[image]

However, when I run it, I get a syntax error:

[image]

From suggested answers below, I tried amending the code to include the `async function` as followings:

[image]

But when I run this, I now get:

```
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Comment: As soon as you try to use an asynchronous function in another function, this function must be asynchronous as well, so here you need to add `async` before `def animate(i)` (so the line becomes `async def animate(i):`). Though if `FuncAnimation` does not take asynchronous function as second argument, this will break. I'm not familiar enough with asynchronous python to give more info, but that's why you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

`await` can only be called in an `async` function, so your `animate` function must be `async` :

```
async def animate(i): 
await socket.__aenter__()
msg = await socket.recv()
x_axis.append(msg['T'])
y_axis.append(msg['p'])

plt.cla()
plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
```

Comment: Hi Baptiste, same question as above- how can I then run this function?

Comment: You are totally free to call your `animate` function synchronously (so you would just call `animate` as always) or asynchronously (so you have to put an `await` before the function call)

Comment: Baptiste, can you try running it? It doesn't work- nothing prints, even when I call animate directly